# ASP.NET Active Directory Membership Provider and SQL Profile Provider

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, membership, provider

I am currently designing a Membership/Profile scheme for a new project I am working on and I was hoping to get some input from others.

The project is a ASP.NET web application and due to the short time frame, I am trying to use any and all built in .NET framework components I can. The site will probably entertain < 5000 users. Each user will have a profile where custom settings and objects will be persisted between visits.

I am required to use an existing Active Directory for authentication. Since the AD schema cannot be extended to hold new fields, I am required to hold user settings and objects in a different data store. I have also been told ADAM is probably not a possible solution.

I was hoping to use the Active Directory Membership Provider for my authentication scheme and the SQL Profile Provider as a user profile data store. I would prefer not to build a custom profile provider, but I do not see this posing much of a problem if need be.

I was wondering if this is even a possible solution, and if so, has anyone had any luck with this approach.

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off - I've never done this myself.

There's a really excellent series (14 !! parts) on the whole topic of ASP.NET 2.0 membership, roles and profile provider systems by Scott Mitchell at [4 Guys from Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx).

According to my understanding, you should be able to configure this behavior you are looking for by using basically these two sections in your web.config:

```
  <!-- configure Active Directory membership provider -->
  <membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
                 System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </providers>
  </membership>

  <!-- configure SQL-based profile provider -->      
  <profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>
      <add name="SqlProvider"
        type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
        connectionStringName="SqlProfileProviderConnection"
        applicationName="YourApplication" />
    </providers>

    <!-- specify any additional properties to store in the profile -->   
    <properties>
      <add name="ZipCode" />
      <add name="CityAndState" />
    </properties>
  </profile>
```

I would think this ought to work :-)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I gave this a shot this morning and everything went well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if we use AD for membership and authentication  and aspnet_profile for storing profile. How's the relationship being created and managed ie. UserID. In other words, how does asp.net knows based on what attribute of AD to generate UserId?

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588265/understanding-wcf-windows-authentication ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to this as replied by Marc :

```
<add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
                 System.Web, Version=2.0.3600, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

you might also need to add

```
connectionStringName="ADService",
attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
```

with corresponnding connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://ServerIP" />
</connectionStrings>
```

If you are using .net 4.0   then you will need to replace

```
Version=2.0.3600
```

with

```
Version=4.0.0.0
```

So finally ,

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="ADService"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
                 System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

and since it is set as default, it can be referenced as :

```
MembershipProvider provider = Membership.Provider;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and tried to do as sugested, but an error is shown:

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

So I discovered that a few changes should be done to the default login form on the VS2012 with MVC 4 and entity framework as follows:

on file "AccountController.cs"

on the "public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)"

Change the

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
```

for

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
```

on the "public ActionResult LogOff()"

Change the

```
    WebSecurity.Logout();
```

for

```
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

and add the following: FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

```
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.Provider.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);               

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: +1 thank you!  This was exactly what fixed the issue for me.  Nowhere else have I come across this information when searching for problems with `AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the information, its helped alot. Also rather than Setting the default Provider with  `MembershipProvider provider = Membership.Provider;`  you can set it with in the membership tag.

`<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">`

I"ve also writen a small how to and a download to a Visual Studio Project and Source configured to use AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.

[ASP.NET Forms Based Authentication - using AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider](http://www.christowles.com/2011/04/aspnet-forms-based-authentication-with.html)