# SharePoint 2007: Use SqlProfileProvider with Windows Integrated Authentication?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to use the **SqlProfileProvider (aspnetdb)** for storing certain profile information for users that are authenticated to a SharePoint 2007 site by Windows Integrated Authentication. The goal is be able to develop ASP.NET code that stores a few personalization strings for each user and will run in an ASP.NET or SharePoint site. I was hoping I could use the SqlProfileProvider and then it would be available in either ASP.NET or SharePoint provided I added the correct provider to **web.config**.

Here's what I have in web.config in the SharePoint web application, however inside my ASPX code-behind **Context.Profile** is always null:

```
<profile automaticSaveEnabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider">
<providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" 
         connectionStringName="aspnetdb" 
         applicationName="simple_test" 
         type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</providers>
<properties>
    <add name="TestName" type="System.String" allowAnonymous="false"/>
</properties>
```

(Note that aspnetdb is a valid connection string elsewhere in the web.config).

Anyone have experience with hooking up the aspnetdb Profile provider in conjunction with Windows Authentication, or does that only work if Forms/membership authentication is in effect? Any other suggestions on how the user settings can be persisted in ASP.NET/SharePoint without having to use cookies or write a data model and access layer from scratch?

Comment: Do you just want to store personalized settings for a web part or do you want to store them for a whole site/web?

Comment: Interesting if this works. My gut feeling is it will screw up some part of SharePoint but worth a try.

Comment: @AdamBT - I'd like to store Profile values on a per-user basis with a scope of the entire web site, or as SharePoint likes to call it the SiteCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more searching and prototyping I managed to stumble across the solution for this thanks to [this MSDN Forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/1224ae5e-10e0-4d21-9d6d-35b7f771b318). SharePoint removes the ASP.NET Profile module, so you have to add it back in to the Web.config httpModules section:

```
<add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule" />
```

There are also some workarounds required to access the Profile attributes defined in web.config so you don't get compile-time errors. You can either develop a custom Provider as [described in Becky's post for forms-based authentication](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=53) or make calls to [Profile.GetPropertyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.getpropertyvalue.aspx) and [Profile.SetPropertyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.getpropertyvalue.aspx) to get and set the profile values for the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Well it should be possible, according to [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781590598917/using_the_sqlprofileprovider) article:

> *Because profiles are stored in a user-specific record, you need to authenticate the current user before you can read or write profile information. **You can use any type of authentication system, including Windows-based authentication and forms-based authentication. The profile system doesn't care—it simply stores the user-specific information** in a record that's identified based on the user ID. Seeing as every authentication system identifies users uniquely by user ID, any authentication system will work.*

But I have never tried it before.

Also, i found this post here on SO, which goes more into detail:

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895002?sort=votes)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am thinking as well is that it should work. I had referenced the SO Post in setting up my Web.config but SharePoint seems to be ignoring it entirely even after a couple of iisresets.